How to clean up redundant headers in cache files when Nginx turns on reverse cache
How to clean up redundant headers in cache files when Nginx turns on reverse cache.
Is it possible to modify the source code? The anti-generation service is a cloudflare.
enter image description here
I tried setting proxy_ignore_headers, but it didn't work
